# Add product to cart using jquery ajax and php in functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

**The goal:** With javascript, make an AJAX request to call a PHP function inside functions.php to add a product to the cart.

For the frontend part, I'm using a snippet WordPress plugin:

```
<?php

global $post;
if($post->ID == 581) {
    ?>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            let pickUpAddress = document.getElementsByClassName("first")[0].getElementsByClassName("stm_filled_pickup_location")[0].textContent;
            let dropOffAddress = document.getElementsByClassName("second")[0].getElementsByClassName("stm_filled_return_location")[0].textContent;

            let location1 = "Carr. Aeropuerto, Punta Cana 23000, República Dominicana";
            let location2 = "57000, República Dominicana";
            let location3 = "Ntra. Sra. del Carmen Street, Las Terrenas 32000, República Dominicana";
            let location4 = "El Catey, Samaná, República Dominicana";
            let location5 = "Ruta 66 Salida Del Aeropuerto Las Americas, Santo Domingo 11336, República Dominicana";
            
            var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
            
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,    
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                data: location1 + '&action=addProductToCart' //action defines which function to use in add_action
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

?>
```

The PHP snippet in functions.php:

```
function addProductToCart(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( 204 );
}

add_action('wp_ajax_addProductToCart', 'addProductToCart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_addProductToCart', 'addProductToCart'
```

Why this doesn't work? I have been checking on Internet a lot of time and it seems correct.

(Once I get the product added to the cart, I want to compare the different locations, but I'll do that myself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have passed wrong parameterized content to **action**. You need to update as per below.

```
data: {'location':location1, 'action':'addProductToCart'} //action defines which function to use in add_action
```

#### Try below Code

```
<?php

global $post;
if($post->ID == 581) {
    ?>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            let pickUpAddress = document.getElementsByClassName("first")[0].getElementsByClassName("stm_filled_pickup_location")[0].textContent;
            let dropOffAddress = document.getElementsByClassName("second")[0].getElementsByClassName("stm_filled_return_location")[0].textContent;

            let location1 = "Carr. Aeropuerto, Punta Cana 23000, República Dominicana";
            let location2 = "57000, República Dominicana";
            let location3 = "Ntra. Sra. del Carmen Street, Las Terrenas 32000, República Dominicana";
            let location4 = "El Catey, Samaná, República Dominicana";
            let location5 = "Ruta 66 Salida Del Aeropuerto Las Americas, Santo Domingo 11336, República Dominicana";
            
            var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
            
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,    
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                data: {'location':location1, 'action':'addProductToCart'} //action defines which function to use in add_action
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: It works but when I try to add the product to the cart, it doesn't do anything. But if I ```echo "hello world";``` in my PHP and I print the response in my AJAX, it prints "hello word", but nothing is added to the cart

Comment: 1. Debug for `$woocommerce` is accessing in that variable.
2. Make sure your product id is correct.
3. Refer this url => https://quadmenu.com/add-to-cart-with-woocommerce-and-ajax-step-by-step/